# Getting console width Python 2 Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get a terminal size by doing syscalls in Linux. I am running this code in Python 2.7:

```
def get_terminal_size(subprocess=False):
   import os
   if subprocess:
       rows, cols = [ int(x) for x in
                os.popen("stty size").readline().strip().split()]
   else:
       import termios, fcntl, struct, sys
       s = struct.pack("HHHH", 0, 0, 0, 0)
       x = fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, s)
       rows, cols, x_pixels, y_pixels = struct.unpack("HHHH", x)
   return cols, rows
```

This code gives me this error:

> ImportError: No module named termios

same for fcntl

I checked that these modules exist in Python 2.7.
Please do not suggest me to move to Python 3. I understand that I can easily use built-in get_terminal_size() method in Python 3. But I want to do it in Python 2.7 on purpose.
I do not understand why it fails.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you run the code in a virtualenv? What does `python --version` say? Did you try to reinstall the modules via `pip` ?

Comment: @Jan I created venv and I use Python 2.7.15 there. python --version says Python 2.7.15
And I did not try to reinstall modules via pip. Could you pls explain why and how?

Comment: Does `pip install ...` help?

Comment: @Jan `pip install termios` gives this error: _Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement termios (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for termios_

Comment: There you go, the modules haven't been installed (yet).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @RuslanSaiko I am using RHEL 8

Comment: with a bit of luck you have the `COLUMNS` environment variable available. So you can try this as well: `import os; print(os.environ['COLUMNS'])`

Comment: It feels like you are running the script on a non-UNIX OS. Although RHEL 8 is based on Fedora 28, I cannot say with certainty that the problem is not with the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html) Termios is part of the standard Python Library, therefore there is no need to install it.
A simple `import termios` in your Python script should work.
If this is causing you an error then I assume your Python install is not working properly and my suggestion is to reinstall Python (or to use a Virtual Environment).